# Magento Terms and conditions checkbox not showing on checkout page review section

Tags: magento, conditional-statements, checkout, review

My site is created in Magento 1.8. It's working much well with all the extensions I have installed, but there is one issue in the checkout page.

While I enables Terms & Conditions from admin configuration section and create Terms & Condition from Sales > Terms and Condition section, it's not displaying on checkout page review section.

The strange thing is, while I clicks on Place Order button it shows message, "Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.", but I can't see checkbox for this.

I check it by disabling all the extensions I have installed in my site, but still no success.

I also tried to check code in app/code/core/mage/checkout/block/Agreement.php file I found it fetches Terms & Conditions I created  and passes to below function,

$this->setAgreements($agreements);

but it returns null in last line

return $this->getData('agreements');

I am not getting what the issue is? Is any body have idea about this? Please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable Terms and coditions at [**System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options**]  but you also need to create and activate at least one term at [**Sales->Terms and Condition -> Add New Condition**].

More details at http://magento-chef.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/How-to-enable-terms-and-condition-check-box-in-checkout-step-page-in-your-Magento-store.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable Onepage Checkout [System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options]

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-the-terms-and-conditions-of-a-sale

> Note: To enable Terms and Conditions, Onepage Checkout must be
>   enabled. If Onepage Checkout is disabled, the Terms and Conditions
>   will not appear during checkout.